ValueError - что за ошибка при запуске кода для Telegram на компьютере
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
# Use your own values from my.telegram.org
api_id =000000
api_hash ='00000000000000000000000000'

# The first parameter is the .session file name (absolute paths allowed)
with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))

async def main():
    while True:
        await client.send_message(000000000000, '/Любой текст/')
        time.sleep(60)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())


Подскажите в чем проблема ? Суть процесса в том - что код отправляет сообщения за меня в телеграмм. Но после запуска на компьютере, я получаю тестовое сообщение себе в Избранное телеграмм - но в группу не пишет, хотя я указал id группы - куда нужно писать
ответ после запуска
PS C:\Users\Я> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Я\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete   
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Я\main.py", line 13, in main
    await client.send_message(0000000000, '/Любой текст/')
  File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 840, in send_message
    entity = await self.get_input_entity(entity)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 468, in get_input_entity
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=00000000000) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.
PS C:\Users\Я>


Вас не смущает id пользователя 000000000000?

я просто написал нули - но реально там указаны правильные id - взятые через бот Get my ID

У вас даже в трейсе нули в качестве id, а такого быть не может. Или вы абсолютно везде специально выставили нули?

да просто поставил нули,,, в исходном коде там все цифры правильно написаны - я не думаю что от того что будут нули или настоящие цифры - этот как то повлияет на разгадку происходящей ошибка
